# How to optimize NGINX for video viewing?

Tags: nginx

Currently, video is very slow and it often freezes on my react native app even when the connection is good. How can I optimize the server to send video faster?

here is my current config

```
upstream currentConfig {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name x.xx.xxx.xxxx;
    root /home/ubuntu;
    client_max_body_size 4G;

    location /Users/ {
        aio threads;
        client_body_buffer_size 1m;
        proxy_read_timeout 500;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    location / {
        client_body_buffer_size 16k;
        proxy_read_timeout 500;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the specific problem with the video?

Comment: the video will start and play for 10-15 seconds and then will pause for buffering. It is a 3 minute video, i think it may have something to do with buffer limits, though I do not have a lot of experience configuring NGINX

Comment: This is a... MP4 file or something?  The video is served from `/Users/`, or is it from some upstream server?  And, what do your browser's developer tools say on the client-side?

Comment: yes they are MP4 files, and I am not sure how to use the react native debugger for this type of issue, if you have any good resources do let me know

Comment: Probably a better way in this case is to use Fiddler.  https://www.telerik.com/fiddler  Watch the HTTP request/responses come through and see if you can figure out what the issue is.  The browser will usually make multiple ranged requests, and if the server drops off then the browser should make a fresh request for the remaining data.  This sometimes doesn't work this way.

Comment: thank you I will try it out and see if I can find the issue!